# Django sitemap for dynamic static pages

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-sitemaps

I have the following in my **views.py**:

```
ACCEPTED = ["x", "y", "z", ...]

def index(request, param):
    if not (param in ACCEPTED):
        raise Http404
    return render(request, "index.html", {"param": param})
```

Url is simple enough:

```
path('articles/<str:param>/', views.index, name='index'),
```

How do I generate a sitemap for this path only for the accepted params defined in the `ACCEPTED` constant? Usually examples I've seen query the database for a list of detail views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are solutions in the Django documentation for your case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-for-static-views

For your pages, do something like that:

```py
class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'daily'

    def items(self):
        return ['x', 'y', 'z', ...]

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(index, kwargs={"param": item})
```